# Transfer file from server to ubuntu subsystem in windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, putty, file-transfer, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scp

I am currently working on a windows 10 laptop. I have installed the `ubuntu subsystem` (instead of PUTTY) in it to access the remote server. When I launch the `ubuntu subsystem` from my windows start menu, it opens with a command prompt `user@PC01Y21-PC`

The remote server is a Linux server as well.

In addition, I am connected to a VPN. If I don't connect to the VPN, I will not be able to login to the remote server.

So, what I would like to do is download the file from a remote server to my laptop

1. From ubuntu subsystem, I use SSH 172.11.222.8 9 (IP address of remote server)
2. Later I navigate to the path where the file is
3. I type `pwd` to get the path of the file
4. Later I type the below command

   `scp selva@172.11.222.8:/home/test/project/data/abc/map.csv user@PC01Y21-PC:/home/user/`

I was expecting that this command would work and the file would be saved in the `user` folder of `ubuntu subsystem` but I get the below error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pc01y21-pc: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

I would like to copy the map.csv file to the `/home/user/` folder in ubuntu system.

Later, I will move it to `/mnt/c/` folder so I can access it from my laptop

Can help me please?

Comment: Your PC `PC01Y21-PC` is unknown from your server without some sort of dynamic DNS update or some broadcast forwarding wizardry.
Instead, from your ubuntu subsystem do: `scp selva@172.11.222.8:/home/test/project/data/abc/map.csv /home/user/anywhere_you_want`

Comment: @LaurentGosselin - May I seek your help on this? I am trying to transfer a file from local WSL to my remote server. So, I tried the below command but it resulted in error as shown below `scp /mnt/c/Users/test/Downloads/DC_records.csv test@172.xx.xxx.x:/home/test/records.csv`

Comment: I got the error which reads as `ssh: connect to host 172.xx.xxx.x port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
lost connection`

Comment: Here, `172.xx.xxx.x` is the ip address of my remote server

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following as you don't need to mention the local computer name:

`scp selva@172.11.222.8:/home/test/project/data/abc/map.csv /home/user/`

Comment: upvoted for the response