# Transfer file from SSH server on Windows substem for Linux (Ubuntu) to Windows

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working at home on a Windows 10 machine, I have installed the `Ubuntu Windows Substem Linux` terminal and am using it to ssh into a server: user@md47. There are some images I would like to transfer to my Windows machine. I have read about using SCP for this purpose, however

```
scp user@md47:/home/user/testfile.txt /home/user
```

Transfers the file to the file system of *the server* I am SSH'ed into and not to the Windows Subsystem structure I have. I tried because it was the suggested answer in this thread ([Transfer file from server to ubuntu subsystem in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1568532/transfer-file-from-server-to-ubuntu-subsystem-in-windows-10)) but as mentioned, this solution does not transfer the *file* to my local drive.

I have the Linux terminal running as: `user@DESKTOP-BCSDE87` on my Windows machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to use scp or another tool to transfer a file from an SSH server onto Windows 10 via the WSL?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scp without ssh'ing into any other computer. From the WSL system, just copy the file over:

```
scp user@ip:/path/to/file /path/to/save
```

That will copy the file over. If you want to do it while ssh'ing into a pc, invert the order of the arguments:

```
scp /path/to/file user@ip:/path/to/save
```

The user and IP need to be the ones corresponding to the remote PC on the first example, and the WSL system on the second one.

Comment: Wow, of course, I can just use SCP from a new terminal where I am not SSH'ed into the server... So obvious in hindsight, but your comment is greatly appreciated!